# Binary and dotted decimal conversion for looping over ip addresses

Tags: c++, binary, network-programming

I am trying to loop over the ip addresses in a subnetwork to print them along with the DNS names of hosts. I have the network mask and an ip address that belongs to it. Since I need to use some "networking functions: inet_addr, and gethostbyaddr" I am storing the addresses in an array of char, but now I dont know how to use the binary addresses I have to loop over all hosts in network without having a very complicated conversions between formats .. Any suggestions for approaching this problem ?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    struct hostent *hostPtr; // holds the IP addresses, aliases ... etc
   char* addr_ptr; 

   char network_mask[] = "255.255.255.0";
   char ip_addr_dot[] = "165.95.11.15";
   u_long ip_addr_long = = inet_addr(ip_addr_dot);//dotted decimal ip to binary;
   u_long network_mask_long = inet_addr(network_mask); //dotted decimal network mask to binary;
   u_long network_address_long = = ip_addr_long & network_mask_long; // binary network address  

   u_long starting_address = network_address_long + 1; //must be a binary operation
   u_long current_address = starting_address;
   int no_of_hosts; // how to find it

  // This is the way I think I need to approach it, unless there is a better way for doing that ..   
   /* for(int i = 0; i < no_of_hosts; i++){
        current_address += 1; // must be done in binary
        addr_ptr = (char *) &current_address;   
        hostPtr = gethostbyaddr(addr_ptr, 4, AF_INET);

        if (hostPtr == NULL){

              printf(" Host %s not found\n", ip_addr_dot);
        }
        else {

              printf("The IP address %s:\t", inet_ntoa(*addr_ptr));
              printf("The official name of the site is: %s\n", hostPtr->h_name); 

        }
   }*/

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are these always IPv4 addresses?

Comment: yes .. I am assuming that for now.

Answer (score 0):

This gets you the maximum number of hosts on the subnet:

```
u_long no_of_hosts = (network_address_long | ~network_mask_long) - network_address_long - 1;
```

You have the starting address, iterating should be straightforward.
Let me share with you some old C function that I wrote to get the dot-decimal string from an unsigned int32 (u_long in your code):

```
void Int2DotDec(u_long ip, char* buf)
{   u_long b0 = ip & 0xFF, remain = ip >> 8;
    u_long b1 = remain & 0xFF; remain = remain >> 8;
    u_long b2 = remain & 0xFF; remain = remain >> 8;
    u_long b3 = remain & 0xFF;
    snprintf(buf, 16, "%d.%d.%d.%d", b3, b2, b1, b0);
}
```

p.s: purists pardon me, this C-Style thing is old stuff and worked well for me. Just size correctly the buf parameter (`char buf[16]`).

Answer (score -1):

`scanf` is your friend:

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
scanf(ipString, "%u.%u.%u.%u", &a, &b, &c, &d);
__uint32_t ip=(a<<24)|(b<<16)|(c<<8)|d;
```

The `scanf()` function is the anti-these of printf. It is capable to convert and interpret strings.

Best if you separate this string-to-ip conversion into a separate function.